# set up the input value asynchronously

Tags: php, html, ajax

I would like to put the value of an input asynchronously to optimize the display performance of my page.

Here is the piece of code I would like to use with an AJAX call except that I do not know how to make this call in the input.

```
<td class="why_input_wrapper">
   <input id="plan_link_url;<?php echo $plan_infos; ?>" value="<?php echo RcaviewController::getBrand($brand_owner[0]); ?>"/>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$inputid = "plan_link_url;$plan_infos;";
?>
<td class="why_input_wrapper">
   <input id="<?= $inputid ?>" value=""/>
</td>
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Rcaview/getBrand",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                brand: "<?= $brand_owner[0]; ?>,
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("error");
            },
            success: function (res) {
                if (res) {
                   jQuery("#<?= $inputid ?>").val(res);
                }
            }
});
});
</script>
```

A lot of things have to be changed according to your structure and code, that is not shown in the question.
In this reply, I am assuming that:

1. the input id is "`plan_link_url;$plan_infos;`", as far as I understand from your code
2. there is a bind between the controller you want to call and the endpoint `/Rcaview/getBrand` (change it if different)
3. It's a POST call with the `brand` param as input and the dataType is JSON (change it if different)
4. The response is simply the value to be added, otherwise please parse the variable `result` accordingly
5. You can use jQuery, otherwise change the way you perform the AJAX call with your preferred library or plain JS, replace `jQuery("#<?= $inputid ?>").val(res);` with `document.getElementById('<?= $inputid ?>').value = res;` and the `ready()` function with `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function()`

Answer (score 0):

**Is your input dependent on some other input if yes then you need to use 
something like following:-**

```
$("dependent_input_id").on("event",function(){
  $.ajax({
        url: "api call url",
        data:{param1:value, param2: value,...},
        success:function(){
          //update the the input
        }
  });
});
```